# Is it possible to change the query analyzer in Solr without reindexing?

Tags: solr

Will changing the *query* analyzer for a Solr field require me to re-index all data before seeing results. Obviously this is true for a *indexing* analyzer, but it seems plausible that I could change a query analyzer without requiring a re-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fine. Just reload the core or restart Solr. I believe you can actually change indexing analyzer too as long you don't change the type of field (e.g. integer, etc). You will just have tokens in the index indexed in the old way, which could be quite confusing.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not required for you to reindex data if you change the query analyzer, But you still need to reload the SOLR core

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=core1
```

Check this page for restriction on reload core command, https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#RELOAD